# remove default error message on invalid field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jquery validation plugin and have the validation working pretty much the way I want, but I've encountered one small issue.

When an input field is validated, I'm displaying a green tick mark next to the input field indicating the field has been successfully validated.

If there are errors on the page, I display an error message at the top of the page indicating the number of invalid fields.

All of this works fine.

The problem occurs if an input field is modified and is no longer valid.  The validation removes removes the green tick mark next to the input field, which is correct, but it then displays the default error message next to the input field.  I do not want to display the error message next to the input field.

How can I remove the default error message text when the field becomes invalid?

Here is a [working demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dman100/tXRjh/5/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    j$(document).ready(function(){

        j$.validator.addMethod("money", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^(\d{1,3})(\.\d{2})$/.test(value);
        }, "Must be in US currency format 0.99");

        var validator = j$('[id$=Details]').validate({
            invalidHandler: function() {
                j$("#error-message").html('<img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.event_ver2, 'images/error-icon.png')}" width="32" height="32">').append(" Please correct the entries highlighted below. " + validator.numberOfInvalids() + " field(s) are invalid.");
            },
            success: function(label, element) {
                label.html('<img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.event_ver2, 'images/success-icon.png')}" width="16" height="16" class="validated">').insertAfter(element);
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        j$('[id$=Email]').rules("add",{
            required: true,
            email: true
        });

        j$('[id$=Credit_Amount]').rules("add",{
            required: true,
            'money': true
        });

        j$('[id$=Credit_Card_Number]').rules("add",{
            required: true,
            creditcard2: function() { return j$('[id$=Credit_Card_Type]').val(); }
        });

        j$('[id$=Verification_Code]').rules("add",{
            required: true,
            digits: true
        }); 

        j$('[id$=Credit_Card_Type]').change(function(){j$('[id$=Details]').validate().element('[id$=Credit_Card_Type]') });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This one was very challenging. I took your jsFiddle and put a `console.log` inside `success:`, `invalidHandler:`, and `errorPlacement:`. To my surprise, none of these fire off when the default error message appears, therefore, I don't see how it can be dynamically removed. Strangely, your green check-mark is enclosed inside the very same `label` element and its `class` is always `.error` whether it contains the default message or the check-mark.  I re-factored your code to make a working solution below.

Answer (score 1):

The main impediment to solving this was that your check-mark is enclosed inside the *same* `label` element as the error message, and its `class` is always `.error` whether it contains the error message or the check-mark.

The only way I could get this working was to permanently eliminate the dynamically generated `label`.

1)  Added an empty `label` next to the `input` in order to totally eliminate the need for this dynamically generated `label`.

```html
<div>
    Email:
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="required" maxlength="30" />
    <label></label>
</div>
```

2) Modified your jQuery to place & remove the checkmark from the sibling `label` element.

```js
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

j$(document).ready(function() {

    var validator = j$("#Details").validate({
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            j$("#error-message")
                .html('<img src="http://shc.dev1.cs3.force.com/MedicalStaffPayment/resource/1355859689000/event_ver2/images/error-icon.png" width="32" height="32">')
                .append(" Please correct the entries highlighted below. " + validator.numberOfInvalids() + " field(s) are invalid.");
        },
        success: function(label, element) {
            j$(element).next('label')
                .html('<img src=http://shc.dev1.cs3.force.com/MedicalStaffPayment/resource/1355859689000/event_ver2/images/success-icon.png width="16" height="16" class="validated">');
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            j$(element).next('label').html('');
        }
    });

    j$("#email").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        email: true
    });
});​
```

[**Working DEMO:**](http://jsfiddle.net/tXRjh/13/)

http://jsfiddle.net/tXRjh/13/

Comment: Hi @Sparky, thanks again for your help!  I just discovered what I think will work as well, but doesn't require a unique id for each span tag.  See the updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dman100/tXRjh/12/)

Comment: @Dman100, that's a good point.  I eliminated the need for a unique `id` and rewrote my answer to reflect this.  Still working as required (based on your original demo) and no `id` required.